# Pass data from PHP to Python Script as multiple variables in array

Tags: python, php, html, mysql

I am trying to implement sentiment analysis through a dashboard, I have various field inputs from various Forms, I want to take input of the Form fields into one array of one form and pass it to python for my Machine Learning algorithm to run and throw the output back.
How do I take the input in form of array and pass it to my python script?

[Here is an example of my php fields in a form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKsBt.png)

[Here is an example of my python code where I want to and plan to replace my single string input to array fields which take every index and perform sentiment analysis, then give an average of the answers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h2n7.png)

Comment: Pass them as command line arguments when PHP invokes the Python script, then Python uses `sys.argv` to get them.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did try in some sample files, but It is showing me NULL as the answer. Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Without seeing the code it's impossible to help you.